# MVC not validate empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have razor file where I define html form with text box for string:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
        </fieldset>
     }
```

The problem is, that I want this field (model.name) not to be nullable, but razor validation allows string to be empty, when I add empty string to model it gives error.
Any suggestions how to validate simply this string not to be empty anymore?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably need to set the DataAnnotation attribute

> [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]

on top of your property  where you want to apply the validation. 
Look at this question here
[RequiredAttribute with AllowEmptyString=true in ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437150/requiredattribute-with-allowemptystring-true-in-asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-valida)

Similar problem, more or less here.

[How to convert TextBoxes with null values to empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475273/how-to-convert-textboxes-with-null-values-to-empty-strings)

Hopefully, you'll be able to solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

what does your viewmodel look like?

You can add a `DataAnnotation` attribute to your `Name` property in your viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field can not be empty.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your controller you can check whether or not the model being posted is valid.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //ok
    }
    else
    {
        //not ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
Use the following line to not accept empty string

```
[Required (AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
```

and this one to not allow white space

```
[RegularExpression (@".*\S+.*", ErrorMessage = "No white space allowed")]
```