# EF Core not raising ValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1, model-validation

I have a base `DbContext` class like

```
public abstract class DbContextBase : DbContext
{
    public DbContextBase()
    {
    }

    public DbContextBase(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.ValidateEntities();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        this.ValidateEntities();

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

     public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
     {
        this.ValidateEntities();

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected virtual void ValidateEntities()
    {
        var entities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().
                            Where(s => s.State == EntityState.Added || s.State == EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
            Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

All my Db Context classes inherit from this base class. The problem is that the line `Validator.ValidateObject()` is not throwing `ValidationException` even when there is a validation violation. In the debugger I can see that this line is executed. For example, for below model class I try calling `SaveChangesAsync()` with `Name` set to `null` but the validation is passing:

```
public class MyModel : IEntity<long>
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`IEntity<T>` just imposes property `Id` on all models.

Comment: If that's the real code, `var entity` is not an entity, but change tracker entry instance. May be you should call it `entry` and then use `entry.Entity`, or add `Select(s => e.Entry)` to the previous line.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I meant `Select(s => s.Entity)`

Comment: @IvanStoev, your suggestion worked. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `entity` does not hold entity instance, but change tracker (`EntityEntry`) instance, so the code is trying to validate the wrong thing.

So either rename the variables and use `entry.Entity` property:

```
var entries = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(s => s.State == EntityState.Added || s.State == EntityState.Modified);

foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entry.Entity);
    Validator.ValidateObject(entry.Entity, validationContext);
}
```

or keep the code as is, but make sure `entities` variable holds enumerable of entity instances:

```
var entities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(s => s.State == EntityState.Added || s.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(s => s.Entity); // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
public class MyModel : IEntity<long>
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### More

- [c# - MVC not validate empty string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511437/mvc-not-validate-empty-string)
- [Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)