# Razor pages PageModel validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

Razor UI validation isnt working at all. When i go to post with empty text boxes it should say that this field is required but it just allows it to go through.

Trying to validate for the PageModel.

`AddApplication.cshtml.cs`

```
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [BindProperty]
        public string appName{get;set;}
```

`AddApplication.cshtml`

```
<input type="text" asp-for="appName" placeholder="Enter Application Name" class="form-control" style="width:25%">
<span asp-validation-for="appName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I already have the `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` included in the start up so i don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511437/mvc-not-validate-empty-string

Comment: Thanks this works. Didn't know that razor passes strings as empty instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Within your getter and setter you need to state that appName is required so it cannot be left blank.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "App Name Is Needed")]
public string appName{get; set;}
```

Without that the name can be left blank as you have seen. With this it should throw an error message after submission that the App Name Is Needed.