# Return empty error message in validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to return empty string for my validation in `ASP.NET MVC 5` project. I have created a property in my view model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(TestResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Empty_Message", ErrorMessage = null)]
public int? TestProperty { get; set; }
```

Inside a view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TestProperty)
```

When I try this one I get the default message "This field is required.". I want it to be empty in this case, because I add a class to error message's `span` element that shows up some icon.

I tried something like that:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
public int? TestProperty { get; set; }
```

...but got an error:

> Either ErrorMessageString or ErrorMessageResourceName must be set, but
>   not both.

Comment: Did you try to use " " (1 space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a space. Example "Space". That would solve your problem.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
public int? TestProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]
```

Reference for more details:
[RequiredAttribute with AllowEmptyString=true in ASP.NET MVC 3 unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437150/requiredattribute-with-allowemptystring-true-in-asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-valida)